# Loading different set of properties in java to an ArrayList

Tags: java, java-io

I have a list of properties like this,

```
server1.serverName =""
server1.serverType ="'
server1.hostName =""
server1.userName =""
server1.password =""
```

in a property file and I have 'n' no of sets,like

`server2, server3,...servern` in a property file. And also I have a class which contain all off these elements with getter and setter method,

```
public class ServerDetails implements Serializable {

  private String serverName;
  private String serverType;
  private String hostName;
  private String userName;
  private String password;
  ...
}
```

Now, I need to read the above property file and create an arraylist like ,

```
ArrayList<ServerDetails> serverDetailsList = new ArrayList<ServerDetails>();
```

where each element of the arrayList should have an object of the class ServerDetails. I need to know how to read the property file and get the server details so that I can create an object and add it to the list.

It seems kind of easy but i lost my way. Kindly help.

Thank you !!

Regards,
Bala

Comment: it is just a simple text file with the extension .propoerties Eg: server.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the properties file into a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object, then loop through the properties like so:

```
int i = 1;
while( properties.get( "server" + i + ".serverName" ) != null ) {
    ServerDetails details = new ...
    details.setServerName( properties.get( [as above] ) );
    ...
    list.add( details );
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the file using Java IO
2. Parse the file line by line. Try storing the 'Key' 'value' pairs in a hashMap, you can then iterate over that adding/updating serverDetails that are stored in your arrayList.

Comment: As noted by the other solutions you could leverage the Java Properties object to do the IO/Parsing for you. You will still need to iterate over the values and build your `serverDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example:

```
private static final String KEY ="server";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("props.properties"));
    int i = 1;
    while (properties.containsKey(KEY + i + ".serverName")) {
        String serverName = properties.getProperty(KEY + i + ".serverName");
        String serverType = properties.getProperty(KEY + i + ".serverType");
        String hostName = properties.getProperty(KEY + i + ".hostName");
        String userName = properties.getProperty(KEY + i + ".userName");
        String password = properties.getProperty(KEY + i + ".password");
        System.out.println(serverName);
        System.out.println(serverType);
        System.out.println(hostName);
        System.out.println(userName);
        System.out.println(password);
        i++;
    }

}
```

props.properties:

```
 server1.serverName =1
 server1.serverType =2
 server1.hostName =3
 server1.userName =4
 server1.password =5

 server2.serverName =6
 server2.serverType =7
 server2.hostName =8
 server2.userName =9
 server2.password =10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("application.properties"));
int i = 1;
String serverNameKey = "server" + i + ".serverName";

while (properties.containsKey(serverNameKey)) {
    String serverName = (String) properties.get(serverNameKey);
            //Read other properties
    // Create new ServerDetails
    // Add to list
    i++;
}
```